# When $(f(T),f'(T))=R[T]$?

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a UFD, $f(T) \in R[T]$ a monic polynomial of degree $d \geq 2$,
and $f'(T)$ the formal derivative of $f(T)$.

When the ideal generated by $f$ and $f'$ equals $R[T]$?

(If $d=1$, then $f'=1$, so obviously $(f,f')=R[T]$).

Comment: When the discriminant of $f$ (or, equivalently, the resultant of $f$ and $f^\prime$) is invertible. (See Fact 7.8 in Chapter III of Lombardi and Quitte, https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.04832v1 .)

Comment: Thank you very much! (you can write it as an answer if you like).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ideal generated by $f$ and $f^\prime$ is the whole $R\left[T\right]$ if and only if the discriminant of $f$ (or, equivalently, the resultant of $f$ and its derivative $f^\prime$) is invertible. This holds in greater generality ($R$ can be any commutative ring, not necessarily a UFD), and is part of Fact 7.8 in

[Henri Lombardi, Claude Quitté, *Commutative algebra: Constructive methods. Finite projective modules*, arXiv:1605.04832v1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.04832v1).